# Creating ipa file with ionic 2, Enterprise account

Tags: ios, ionic2, ipa

I'm trying to create an `ipa` file(for ipad) for an app created with `ionic2`.I have to say it's the first time I do this so I don't even know where to find the signing codes and rest of shit needed for this process.

**What I have**

1. the app
2. Apple Developer Enterprise account
3. ELCapitan OSX on a virtual machine
4. Ionic2, codrova, ... all things required to build the app
5. ios-deploy installed
6. XCode 8.2.1

Can anyone tell me step by step what do I need to do(from `ionic build ios --prod`) and where do I need to go to find the commands for building this app?
I've already seen some older posts here but I have errors on archiving.

Please write down the steps here and don't send me reading other posts.

**Thank you very much for your help!**

This is what I get in XCode > Accounts

**Accounts**
[image: Accounts]

**User**
[image: User]

**Team**
[image: Team]

Comment: Have you looked at the official documents of Ionic 2 on publishing your app? Or provide your error when you tried to do archive

Comment: @Huiting - I've looked now and add some images to the post, I still don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot says you do not have access to create an iOS distribution signing identity. You will need access to that account to proceed on.

I would suggest you go to http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html to see how to publish. It is the official documentation with screenshots of each step.

But here is a general idea of how I distribute my app:

Step 1: Enroll in Apple Developer Program

Step 2: Connect Xcode with your developer account

Step 3: Go to Preferences -> Accounts and select your Apple Id on the left hand side. Click View Details on the bottom right side. A pop up should appear.

Step 4: Create iOS Distribution for signing identities

Step 5: Through Apple Developer Member Center, you need to set up the app ID identifier details. You need to create certificates, identifiers, profiles and devices (optional)

Step 6: Building the app for production. In the root directory of your app, run `ionic build ios --release`. If successful, you  should see BUILD SUCCEEDED in the console. For me, I had to run this command twice to see BUILD SUCCEEDED.

Step 7: Open the project in Xcode (found in platforms/ios/YOURPROJECTNAME.xcodeproj)

Step 8: Create an archive of the application.

- Select `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`. Select `Archive` from the left
  hand side. Make sure the `Build configuration` is set to `Release`

  - To create an archive, choose a `Generic iOS Device`. Next select `Product
    -> Archive`

Step 9: You can choose to Upload to App Store or export as a .ipa file

Let me know if you are still unsure about any parts!

Comment: thanks! I've managed to build but now I have another problem when I try to export as ipa, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814437/cannot-save-for-enterprise-deployment-ios-ipa/42814862?noredirect=1#comment72744047_42814862)