# Cannot "save for Enterprise Deployment", ios ipa

Tags: xcode, ipad, ionic2, ipa

I've developed a ionic 2 app which I want to be able to send through mail or host online somewhere as an iOS app for ipad - so I need to make it **ipa**.

I've got an **Apple Developer Enterprise Program** account type, and **XCode 8.2.1**. I've managed to archive the app with success but when I'm trying to export it I cannot use any method except **"Save for Development Deployment"** which indeed generates an ipa file, but when I try to install it on ipad disappear - the installation starts, works for a half then just disappear.

When I try to **"Save for Enterprise Deployment"**, I choose my team an then it gives me this:
[image]

I've download and install every certificate available from my developer account but with no luck.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I've host the app with **diawi** and when I try to install it from there it gives me his error: `Cannot download the app - "Myapp" cannot be installed > OK or Retry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Provisionning Profile needs > Certificate needs > Signning Identity
>   (Certificate Signing Request CSR)**

The signning identity used to create the certificate is not on your machine.

**Two solutions:**

Export the developer profile from the machine that have the signning identity then import it to your machine.

**OR**

> **Create a new provisionning profile:**
>
> 1. Create a CSR from your machine.
> 2. Create a certificate on the apple member center and upload the CSR.
> 3. Create provisionning profile and select the new certificate.

**Note:** When you create a certificate on apple member center you will be instructed how to create a CSR.
[image]

Comment: Ok, I'll try that 4 days from now. Can you think of reason  why I cannot install the exported ipa? The archive is for ios 10.2.1 latest and I've tryied to install it on a ipad with same ios version and I couldn t install it.

Comment: I've also export an ipa for ios 8 or higher which I can install it on an ipad with os 9 but couldn t install on the ipad with 10.2 - I m thinking is a problem with the ipad and not the app

Comment: Is the UDID of that device included in the provisionning profile? the profile that should be used to sign the app should be an ad-hoc profile and includes the UDID(s) for all the devices that need to install it on.

Comment: I have the enterprise account so I think I don't need the udid - it should work on any device

Comment: I doubt it. but, your deploying is for development that doesnt apply anyway. you should have the udid in there.

Comment: God.... I so hate Apple and all it s shit... You might be right because the iPad that works the app on it is included somewhere but with the other account that expired. Still.... not sure this is the problem. I hope your solution works because being able to send the app without generating for an udid was the whole reason I  bought the enterprise account

Comment: I guess you should include the udid anyway. otherwise, you should try to use testflight or fabric by twitter to distribute apps. this way an invitation will be sent to ppl and there udids will be included automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138135/discussion-between-stx-and-hasan83).