# Can I distribute an Ionic application without using Google Play/App Store?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, publish, ionic3

I will be developing an Ionic app for the first time. It is for a client who wants to distribute the app for his people, so he doesn't want the application to be in the App Store or Google Play, but rather he wants a way to distribute it himself. I'm thinking maybe a web site where the people will go download the app or something like that, if it's possible.

My question is, how can I do this? It's Ionic so it's for both platforms so I need a way that works for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all Android and iOS, both have their own ways to do this.

**Android:**
Yes, you can set up a link to download **.apk** file. So that people will come and download and install from that link. No need for publishing to **PlayStore** at all.

**iOS:**
In iOS, it's not possible to put a link and download that file **.ipa**. Even if he downloads he/she can't install it. So here comes another option in handy without publishing it to **Appstore**. That solution is taking an **enterprise account**. By taking enterprise developer account from apple it provides you a flexibility to distribute among people without uploading to AppStore. It costs 299$/year.

Comment: As I thought. So, can I use this iOS Enterprise Account with an Ionic app? It doesn't have to be native? I'm assuming that it only needs the .ipa so it doesn't actually check if it's a native app.

Comment: Yes. you need to have .ipa file which actually has code signing entities(means proper distribution certificates). Conceptually, it won't check whether native or hybrid. But practically I never implemented this. So before buying get confirmation from Apple as your money shouldn't go waste.

Comment: Here a stackoverflow link that may give idea on how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804289/creating-ipa-file-with-ionic-2-enterprise-account

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you can. Ionic will generate separate native projects in the platforms folder for each platform you built. You can sign those projects separately for private  distribution.

In the case of Android, generating an APK is simple. You can put the .apk anywhere you want (in a web server, for example) and any device can download the .apk as if any file and install it.

For iOS, it is a bit more tricky. First off, you'll need to be part of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program in order to build in-House apps, which costs 299 USD a year. If you're part of the program, you open the XCode workspace generated by Ionic in platforms/ios and follow the process in XCode to archive an .ipa file. You can distribute this file by providing a dowload link in a webserver, the difference is that you don't link to the .ipa itself like you'd do with Android apps, but rather link to a manifest.plist file with all the description of your app, including the location of the .ipa file.

Another option is to use sites like [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com) to distribute your apk and ipa online.

**References:**

[Distributing iOS in-House apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

[Building a release APK with Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-toturial-for-building-a-release-apk/15758)

[manifest.plist example](https://gist.github.com/hramos/774468)

Finally, here's the website the company I work for uses to distribute its own iOS an Android apps, so you can see a working example.

http://www.calymayor.com.mx/appstore/

Comment: Thank you for sharing all the links and also the sample appstore. I missed such samples. If there would be a subpage with a "hello world" demo I can download and install for `.ipa` & `.apk` with source code it would be an amazing bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Hockey App](https://hockeyapp.net/#s) and worked like charm with Ionic.

You have to use [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-hockeyapp) to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think for iPhone you must publish the app on app store, but for android you can simply upload the `.apk` file on your server and then create a download link on website.